# Out of Topic, but please read first

Tags: discussion

Okay, So I am new to askubuntu and LINUX! I am 14 years old, many times I don't understand a thing, I search it on google but when I don't **Comprehand** the answer, So I ask it here, but many people rate me down, so I get blocked :( please tell me a reason to not get that response???

Comment: what's your actual question is?

Comment: @AvinashRaj This was my question http://askubuntu.com/questions/453505/how-to-transform-kali-linux-into-ubuntu! and I got negative votes on it :(

Comment: Why don't you post the above question on [Unix and Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @AvinashRaj Thanks, didn't knew of that :D

Comment: Your questions should be specific to Ubuntu, should include commands and output of what you have tried, and should be as grammatically-correct as possible (no l33t speak) with proper punctuation.  For instance, in your question above, I see several run-on sentences and not a single period.  Things like this might seem like we're being picky, but it makes it easier to read (and answer).

Comment: Your question is also rather broad. There is no "easy" way to install all those tools at once in Ubuntu afaik. Lynis for example, is not in the repositories.

Comment: Guess what I am 14 year old too,  I join when I was 11 or 12 I don't remember which.  I don't think that you get Linux all the way.